# How to convert a byte array to Stream

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert byte[] to stream in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736155/how-do-i-convert-byte-to-stream-in-c)

I need to convert a byte array to a Stream . How to do so in C#?

It is in asp.net application.

FileUpload Control Name: taxformUpload

**Program**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)taxformUpload.FileContent.Length];
taxformUpload.FileContent.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Stream stream = ConvertToStream(buffer);
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `taxformUpload.FileContent` directly? It's already a `Stream`...

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Easy, simply wrap a `MemoryStream` around it:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
```

Answer (score 21):

In your case:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using as what John Rasch said:

```
Stream streamContent = taxformUpload.FileContent;
```