# how to convert System.Byte[] in System.IO.Stream?

Tags: c#, stream

**I can't convert byte to stream.** Is there an easy way to do that?

```
Stream stream;
stream = (Stream) vByte; //something is going wrong in this part. 
//vByte is a byte variable
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736155/how-do-i-convert-byte-to-stream-in-c

Comment: Hmm, is this a Java or a C# question? (see tag)

Comment: @Puce if this is a Java question I need to delete my answer and replace it with `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: I wasn't specified, but seing that Java doesn't have a `System.Byte[]` type it is far more likely to be C#. I have therefore reverted the edit that tagged it Java.

Comment: Ah, it was originally tagged as C#...

Answer (score 8):

You need to instantiate a `MemoryStream` object with the `byte[]`:

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(vByte);
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use cast expressions to convert something to a different type.

Instead, you can create a `MemoryStream` around the array.

In general, the cast operator changes the *compile-time* type of an object to a different type, provided that it actually is an instance of that type at runtime.
For a detailed explanation, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx).