# Image as byte array to Stream

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, type-conversion, azure-cognitive-services

I am taking pictures with my camera and when OnPictureTaken is called i get a byte[ ] data. I am trying to convert the byte array to a System.IO.Stream. This helps me to analise the image in the Project Oxford API. I've tried in countless ways to do this but it seems I can't find a solution. I would be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: You might *write* the byte array to the stream, but not convert it to a stream.  Post just one of those "countless ways" you've tried.  And also read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: @Plutonix System.IO.Stream stream = new MemoryStream();           stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert byte\[\] to stream in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736155/how-do-i-convert-byte-to-stream-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MemoryStream` class, which creates a stream backed by a byte array: [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1167fw72(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Client SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Vision), wich you can get via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision), you need to provide a `Stream` to methods like `VisionServiceClient.AnalyzeImageAsync()`.

You can create a `Stream` out of an `byte[]` and provide it to the SDK like this:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(yourByteArray))
{
    var visionServiceClient = new VisionServiceClient("YOUR_API_KEY");
    var visualFeatures = new VisualFeature[] { VisualFeature.Adult, VisualFeature.Categories, VisualFeature.Color, VisualFeature.Description, VisualFeature.Faces, VisualFeature.ImageType, VisualFeature.Tags };

    var result = await visionServiceClient.AnalyzeImageAsync(stream, visualFeatures);
}
```

**Hint:** In Android you often end up with a `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` object when working with images. Especially when taking pictures with the camera. You can also convert them to streams with `imageBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, stream);` but don't forget to "rewind" the stream with `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`, otherwise the SDK will throw an exception.