# Retrieve C# object from binary that saved in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want save and retrieve an object from a database. I write C# code to save it as below, and it worked fine. Now I can save an object into the database.

```
ReportObject ro = new ReportObject()
{
    Name = ctrl.Name,
    BackColor = ctrl.BackColor,
    ForeColor = ctrl.BackColor,
    Fonts = ctrl.Font,
    TypeofControl = ctrl.GetType()
};

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memStream);

sw.Write(ro);

string sql = "INSERT INTO [TemplateDetails] ([Object]) VALUES (@Object)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con, tran);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Object", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);
cmd.Parameters["@Object"].Value = memStream.GetBuffer();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am already saved a C# object `ReportObject` in SQL Server database. I want to retrieve it back to a C# object.

```
string sql = "SELECT [Object] FROM [TemplateDetails]"

SqlDataReader dr = db.Reader(sql);

if (dr.Read())
{
byte[] arrays = (byte[])dr["Object"];
}
```

Comment: Use binary serialization instead.

Comment: `StreamWriter.Write(Object)` calls the object's `ToString()` method.  Did you override it to return more than just the type name?

Comment: @Amy No, I didn't override  ToString()

Comment: Then you aren't writing anything useful to your table.

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736155/how-do-i-convert-byte-to-stream-in-c).

Comment: @Amy thanks ,  I Solved problem myself. first Serialize to a byte array and save in database.after retrieving from the database as a byte array. Deserialize and convert to object. and it's worked fine. see the detail code in answer session. thanks. to find out my problems

Answer (score 2):

I Solved problem myself. 
 first Serialize to a byte array and save in database.

```
enter  ReportObject ro = new ReportObject()
     {
       Name = ctrl.Name,
       BackColor = ctrl.BackColor,
       ForeColor = ctrl.BackColor,
       Fonts = ctrl.Font,
       TypeofControl = ctrl.GetType()
     };

     MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
     BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
     bf.Serialize(memorystream, ro);
    byte[] yourBytesToDb = memorystream.ToArray();
```

after retrieving from the database as a byte array.  Deserialize and convert to object.

```
MemoryStream memorystreamd = new MemoryStream(arrBytes);
BinaryFormatter bfd = new BinaryFormatter();
ReportObject deserializedReportObject = bfd.Deserialize(memorystreamd) as ReportObject;
```