# ASPXRichedit cannot implicity convert byte[] to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, stream, devexpress, byte

I am using the Devexpress control: aspxichedit following this source code:
https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-use-aspxrichedit-to-edit-rtf-data-in-aspxgridviews-editform-t260978/blob/15.1.5%2B/CS/Default.aspx.cs

and at the code:

```
protected void re_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ASPxRichEdit richEdit = sender as ASPxRichEdit;
    GridViewEditItemTemplateContainer container = richEdit.NamingContainer as GridViewEditItemTemplateContainer;

    string documentID = GetDocumentID(container.Grid);
    if (!OpenedCanceledDocumentIDs.Contains(documentID)) {
        OpenedCanceledDocumentIDs.Add(documentID);
    }

    if (container.Grid.IsNewRowEditing) {
        richEdit.DocumentId = documentID;
        return;
    }

    //for text in db
    string rtfText = container.Grid.GetRowValues(container.VisibleIndex, "RtfContent").ToString();

    //for binary in db
    //byte[] rtfBinary = (byte[])container.Grid.GetRowValues(container.VisibleIndex, "RtfContent");

    richEdit.Open(documentID, DocumentFormat.Rtf, () => {
        //for text in db
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfText);

        //for binary in db
        //return rtfBinary;
    });
}
```

At return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfText);

I kept getting the error 'Cannot implicity convert byte[] to System.IO.Stream' when all online documentations uses byte[] to open the document in the control.

What could be happening? Why is my byte array not being accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurred because the third parameter of `ASPxRichEdit.Open()` expects return type of `System.IO.Stream` type as provided in [this reference](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxRichEdit.ASPxRichEdit.Open.method(_7re7g)), but you're passing byte array with [`GetBytes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public void Open( 
   string documentId,  
   DocumentFormat format,  
   Func<Stream> contentAccessorByStream // => requires return type of stream
)
```

To fix this issue, try to convert that byte array to stream before returning it as in example below:

```
richEdit.Open(documentID, DocumentFormat.Rtf, () => {
    //for text in db
    var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfText);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray); // convert to stream

    return stream;
});
```

Related issue:

[How do I convert struct System.Byte byte[] to a System.IO.Stream object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736155/how-do-i-convert-struct-system-byte-byte-to-a-system-io-stream-object-in-c)